# MSQL: best way to stop a LOAD DATA INFILE command

Tags: mysql

On a 5.5.23 server (stuck there at this point) I have a long running LOAD DATA INFILE statement that I need to stop because it's not working as I expected and I don't want to wait a few hours for it to finish. The table is InnoDB and I don't mind if it gets destroyed, I can recreate it easily.

What is the best way to stop this job without risking damage to anything other than this table? What if I just control-C this command?

Answer (score 0):

Connect to your MySQL database as a user with the SUPER privilege (i.e. root) ; find the correct process with [`SHOW PROCESSLIST`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-processlist.html) :

```
mysql> SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
Id: 3113
User: dumbass
Host: localhost
db: example
Command: Query
Time: 0
State: NULL
Info:  LOAD DATA INFILE 
...
*************************** 2. row ***************************
Id: 3123
User: hbruijn
Host: localhost
db: example
Command: Query
Time: 0
State: NULL
Info: SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST
```

and [`kill`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/kill.html)  the offending thread.

```
mysql> KILL QUERY 3113
```

Comment: You can also kill your own connections (where the same user owns both threads) without `SUPER`.

Comment: Please do not add a comment or an Answer to say "Thank you". - If you want to say "thank you," [vote up](http://serverfault.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that person's answer, or simply pay it forward by providing a great answer to someone else's question. - See [this FAQ page](http://serverfault.com/help/someone-answers) with regards to the etiquette on ServerFault and related sites. - (If this is an Answer to a Question you yourself asked then you additionally have the option to accept it as the correct answer.)